# Bootstrap 3 - when to end the row?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, twitter-bootstrap-3

This might seem like a silly question, but where is the proper place to end the row div using bootstrap 3 and it's alternative layouts based on screen size. Consider the following, a 2 column grid on small devices and a 3 column grid on large, which is correct?

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">A</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">B</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">C</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">D</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">E</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">F</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

OR

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">A</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">B</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">C</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">D</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">E</div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4">F</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The difference is whether I end the row div after a large row is full, or after a small row is full? Or something completely different?

Answer (score 0):

You end the row when you want to control where a break will appear.
Sure you can stuff things in a row even though the columns wont add up to exactly 12. 
But if you really want good control over your display, then you wont do that over often.